# How to change service type to ALB in AWS EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-elb, amazon-eks

I have a deployment and serivce of my application running in my AWS EKS cluster the service is exposed as loadbalancer of type NLB by adding this annotation **service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb** however when i tried to switch it to ALB by changing the annotation to **service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: alb** it created a classic loadbalancer which means that this annotation is not taken into consideration, so is there any way to expose the service on ALB ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the [ALB Ingress Controller](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html).

> The AWS ALB Ingress Controller for Kubernetes is a controller that triggers the creation of an Application Load Balancer (ALB) and the necessary supporting AWS resources whenever an Ingress resource is created on the cluster with the kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb annotation.

This is the [git-repo](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller), and these are the [annotations](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/ingress/annotation/) you can include on your Ingress, and this is [the helm chart](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/incubator/aws-alb-ingress-controller) you can use to deploy it if you prefer.

As an anecdote, it works great.  The only downside is it creates one ALB per Ingress.  To get around this I have been using the [merge-ingress-controller](https://github.com/jakubkulhan/ingress-merge) in conjunction with it, which results in one ALB for multiple ingresses.

Comment: can you use this if you're running your EKS nodes on EC2?

Comment: Yes all of my worker nodes are run on Ec2.  The flow ends up being:
`ingress -> service -> pods`

where the pod ips get registered in target groups that the ALB routes to via the rules you specify in your ingress definition.  The target groups get created and managed by the ALB Ingress Controller

Comment: What if i wanted to use the ALB directly when i set the service type to loadbalancer without the need of ingress is that possible ?

Comment: I don't think you can, but what you can do is have the ALB ingress controller manage your ALB and have it route to existing Target Groups.  This is something I do in one use case.  You can do this using this annotation
`alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.forward-single-tg: >
      {"Type":"forward","TargetGroupArn": "arn-of-your-target-group"}`